# Glyphicon showing as box with hex code inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm having trouble with the collapse button. I am trying to display a glyphicon on the button and make it change when i click on it. A right arrow and down arrow when collapsed. On other pages the glyphicons work. This one though is on the navbar. It is showing as a box with the hex code inside. I have been looking at questions for a couple of hours now and they pretty much missed the font-family. I have a part that is working so it's different and i can't find the problem.

```
<button type="button" aria-expanded="false" class="btn navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
    <span class="sr-only">Ouvrir la navigation</span>
</button>
```

this is the css part where the glyphicons are working :

```
.liens:before {
    content: "\e144";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: -20px;
    color: #2A3E53;
}
```

[image]

I can see the glyphicon on each item in the ul but on the nav I have the exact same css but it shows as a box with hex code for it ie: e250

```
button.btn.collapsed:before {
    content: "\e250";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    color: #2A3E53;
}
button.btn:before {
    content: "\e252";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    color: #2A3E53;
}
```

This is what i get :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that 'Glyphicons Halflings' has this Unicode definition?

Comment: It's on the [website here](http://glyphicons.com/). Must be the 'get pro-version here' then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore how the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) file defines the `Glyphicons Halflings` font-family:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

So I guess you need to check the path to `glyphicons-halflings-regular.*` files.

I've used Bootstrap's [default navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) as a sample, deleted the `.btn` class and simplified your CSS. Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
.navbar-toggle:after {
  content: "\e252"; /* glyphicon-triangle-bottom */
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e250"; /* glyphicon-triangle-right */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-example" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Ouvrir la navigation</span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-example">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, everything was working though except the glyphicon would not show. When making a new project in visual basic the bootsrap came with version 3.0 I just updated to 3.3.7 and it's working perfectly! When I saw your link to 3.3.6 that was it.

Comment: @SteveMorin Oh, that's interesting. [Bootstrap 3.0](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css) contains `Glyphicons Halflings` without `\e250` and `\e252`.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky [BS 3.3.6](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) has them (not sure how to do a new line):   
 `.glyphicon-triangle-right:before {
  content: "\e250";
}
.glyphicon-triangle-left:before {
  content: "\e251";
}`

Comment: @JasonRice Yes, I took the values ​​for the `content` property from these lines. I copied code of `.glyphicon-triangle-bottom:before` and `glyphicon-triangle-right:before` because the author of the question uses the values ​​`\e252` and `\e250` in his code.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky alright. Maybe I misread your response as you said that the BS 3.0 doesn't have \e250 and \e252. Perhaps those were added in 3.3.6

Comment: @JasonRice Yes, I wrote about BS 3.0.0 in the comments to SteveMorin and added a link to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css This file does not have `\e250` and` \e252`, and this was news to me too.